# How does a qualified intermediary make money?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

Can they invest client money and make money on the return on investment, or do they charge fees directly to the client?

Comment: I've added the united-states tag because I'd never heard of this concept before, and a google seems to show it's a specific legal role in US real estate law. Please remove the tag if it's not appropriate (and add a broader explanation of what you mean in that case).

Comment: @Vicky  Yep, sounds good. Yes, it is specific to the US at least, I have not heard of this concept in my country either...  Aa I understand it, the concept is that if you want to defer taxes on the sale of real estate in the US, and thus achieve a closed loop tax system where you only pay tax once you exit that loop, you have to give your money to a QI, and then find a new property to buy within the next 6 months.... My question is how this QI makes money...

Comment: For "1031 exchanges" [this page](https://www.cwscapital.com/insights/qualified-intermediary-fees-what-you-can-expect-during-your-1031-exchange/) talks of direct fees being paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This FAQ on Qualified Intermediary fees](http://www.exeter1031.com/1031_exchange_fees_costs_charges.aspx) seems to cover the basics. This is reinforced by [another primer on 1031 exchange fees](https://www.cwscapital.com/insights/qualified-intermediary-fees-what-you-can-expect-during-your-1031-exchange/).

> Set-up and administrative fees typically only make up about one-third of a Qualified Intermediary's tax-deferred exchange revenue.  The majority of their 1031 Exchange revenue, or about two-thirds, is comprised of interest income earned and retained on the 1031 Exchange funds.  Qualified Intermediaries will retain or share all or a portion of the interest income earned on your tax-deferred exchange funds while they are on deposit or held by the Qualified Intermediary.

It sounds like a mix of straight fees as well as the ability to use the clients money while they hold it.

Comment: Very interesting... Sounds very lucrative, as many of these hold vast sums of money... Sounds like they essentially are able to obtain large amounts of free debt...

Comment: To be fair, holding large amounts of someone elses money and using it to make money is the primary school explanation of what banks do.

Comment: Yes, but it seams like an interesting way of achieving the same thing, but possibly with less regulation, and a lower barrier to entry...